# How to add widget to appear only when sharing to social

Tags: flutter

I tried `share package` and it works but I want to add a `Widget` that **only appears on the shared image**, not on the app. So please help me this is the code so far:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _contentKey = GlobalKey();
  final bool forSharing;

  HomePage({
    Key key,
    this.forSharing = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
            onPressed: () => onTakeScreenShotAndSharing(
              'Image',
              _contentKey.currentContext,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: RepaintBoundary(
        key: _contentKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            if (forSharing) Text('Text appear only for Sharing'), // This is the widget that I want it appear only on the shared image
            Text('Content'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTakeScreenShotAndSharing(String fileName, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = context.findRenderObject();
      final image = await boundary?.toImage();
      final bytes = await image?.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
      if (bytes == null || bytes.buffer == null) return;
      final dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
      final file = File('$dir/$fileName${DateTime.now().toString()}.png');
      final newFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
      await Share.shareFiles([newFile.path]);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package

Comment: @Kahou could you pls help me implement it in my code? I am a newbie xD

Comment: The screenshot package has a  complete example.